# Data is stored in db but when app is closed and opened fro next time, it displays nothing

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am storing my data in db and displaying in recyclerview using adapter. But once I close the application and open it again the it does not display any data.
Db should save my data in recyclerview, sholudn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I just pasted the same code which I used in onActivityResult method in the main activity.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            ItemList  listData = new ItemList();
            listData.setListId(cursor.getInt(0));
            listData.setDataList(cursor.getString(1));
            listData.setDone(cursor.getInt(2));
           /* Log.e("Main activity", "ID: " + listData.getListId());
            Log.e("Main activity", "Text: " + listData.getDataList());
            Log.e("Main activity", "done: " + listData.getDone());*/
            itemList.add(listData);
            itemAdapter.notifyItemInserted(itemList.size());

        }
```

Comment: But still I am not able to scroll. Please can anyone help? Thanks